Bad Result with NLTK's ResolutionProver in FOL (Python)
I'm working on a project using First-Order Logic (FOL) in Python with NLTK. I'm trying to build a simple knowledge base (KB) about Hogwarts houses and use the ResolutionProver to draw inferences. However, I'm encountering an unexpected result with my code.
Here's the code snippet:

from nltk.sem import Expression
from nltk.inference import ResolutionProver

# Define a parser for the logic expression
read_expr = Expression.fromstring

# Define BelongsTo relation
BelongsTo = read_expr(r'\ s h. BelongsTo(s, h)')

h_in_houses = read_expr(r'\ h. (h = Gryffindor | h = Hufflepuff | h = Ravenclaw | h = Slytherin)')

kb = []
kb.append(read_expr(r'(BelongsTo(Gilderoy, Gryffindor) | BelongsTo(Gilderoy, Ravenclaw))'))
kb.append(read_expr(r'not BelongsTo(Gilderoy, Gryffindor)'))

# Verify if the conclusion can be inferred from the knowledge base
prover = ResolutionProver()
print(prover.prove(read_expr(r"BelongsTo(Gilderoy, Ravenclaw)", kb)))

My Expectation:
I expect the code to print True because the knowledge base states that Gilderoy belongs to either Gryffindor or Ravenclaw, and we explicitly deny his membership in Gryffindor. This should logically lead to the conclusion that Gilderoy belongs to Ravenclaw.
The Problem:
However, the code currently prints False. I'm confused about why the ResolutionProver doesn't infer the conclusion I was expecting.
My Question:
Could someone please help me understand why this code doesn't work as anticipated?  Is there a mistake in my logic representation or how I'm using the ResolutionProver? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
